# Cordova Application scaling issue in emulator ios

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I am trying to create a small chart application for iOS using cordova. When I ran the application in browser the chart is scaled to the width of the my browser, though I have reduced the size of it and it looks perfect, but when I ran the same in iOS emulator, it doesn't scale and I had to scroll horizontally and vertically to view the entire chart. I am not sure where I am missing it. Below is the image, left side is the browser one and right is the emulator one, as you can see emulator one doesn't show up the entire chart. I tried both iPhone 6 and iPhone 4S emualtors and still faced the same issue.

[image: Chart Image Browser vs iOS Emualtor]

Comment: Please show your viewpoint settings.

Comment: You mean ViewPort? If so, here is what I have:      <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

Comment: Sorry, yes, I mean viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the viewport to:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
```

Comment: I initially tried with initial-scale=1 and maximum-scale=1 but it didn't work, that's when I changed it to 0.5